# code for removing date or week or month from today date

Tags: java, date, calendar

I need to get the date based on the following condition,

From the current date, If the user selects only date(1-31), must subtract it from the current date and get the new date.

If the user selects weeks(1-53) then we have to remove the selected no'of weeks from the current dates no'of weeks and get a new date.

If the user selects only months(1-12) then we have to delete the selected number of months from the current date months and get a new date.
Sample code for date checking..

```
Calendar today=Calendar.getInstance();  
int month=today.MONTH;  

int year=today.YEAR;  
today.clear();  
today.set(year, month,dateOfMonth);
date=today.getTime();
```

Any Logic is highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you please explain it with an example ?

Comment: Do you have some code that you've written already? If not, this looks like Homework.

Comment: Take a look at [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(currentDate);
if (inDays) {
  cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -n);
} else if (inWeeks) {
  cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -n);
} else if (inMonths) {
  cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve all of this using :

```
java.util.Calendar.add(int, int)
```

For instance:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -10); // substracts 10 days from 'now'
```

Comment: @Mr.Chowdary -- i need ur help on one of your questions you asked about uploading a file to filenet using Java. Please send me any info you have on my email id: ajitsinghsethi@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Add days to a date:
http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html#plus(int)